# How to set field permission on same field for different content type

Tags: entities, users

I have two content type A and B and I have created a field in A by name a1, which I have used in other content type B, so A and B both have field a1.

Now, I have installed Field Permission module, and assigned permission on field a1 for Content Type A, now I want to assign permission on a1 for content type B, but on assigning permission to a1 in content type B, it is changing field permission that of A also.

Please provide me a solution for it.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/118591/17003), check it out.

Comment: Here is a discussion on the subject https://www.drupal.org/node/1221186